# What can be concluded about an equilibrium point that has finitely many trajectories that converge to it?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-topology, dynamical-systems, control-theory, stability-in-odes

If you have a dynamical system $\dot{x}=f(x)$ and $f(x)$ is smooth , given that $f(x_0)=0$ and only finitely many trajectories converge to $x_0$ . I think if $x_0$ is isolated then the stable manifold is one dimensional since if it was more than one dimensional it would have infinitely many . I also think that the number of trajectories can be at most two .

My questions are :

**1) If $x_0$ is isolated , is the stable manifold of $x_0$ only one dimensional and If yes is the smoothness condition needed ?

2) If $x_0$ is not isolated can other conditions be imposed so that the same conclusion can be said ?**

Edit : I think I could use the linearization of the system at $x_0$ as $\dot{x}=Ax$ , so if the system has one stable eigenvector $v_1$ ,   since trajectories cannot intersect it will have only two stable trajectories $v_1$ and $-v_1$ , if there is another stable eigenvector then the whole plane containing the two vectors will be stable implying there is an infinite number of trajectories . However , this doesn't include the cases where the linearization fails or non-isolated points case .

Comment: Are you sure that such a system even exists? Do you have an example where only finitely many trajectories converge to $x_0$?

Comment: $\dot{z}=Az$ and $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$ the y-axis is stable and only has two trajectories which pass by either $[0 \ \ 1]$ or $[0 \ \ -1]$

Comment: Ok, you count the solution from $x = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T$ as the same trajectory like for example the solution starting from $x = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}^T$.

Comment: yes indeed , if you start at $z=[0 \ \ 2]$ then you will be pass by $z=[0 \ \ 1]$ after some time $t$ .

Comment: But if you start at $z = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0.5 \end{bmatrix}^T$ then you won't pass by $z = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T$... I am not sure if this really "counts" as finitely many because there exists no $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that every solution starting at $z = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & y_0 \end{bmatrix}^T$ will pass by $z = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & c \end{bmatrix}^T$ (except zero).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110871/discussion-between-abc1455-and-sampletime).